# WPF UI thread does not resume after modal dialog is closed - Intermittent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

In my WPF application, I process some operation under Task like this:

```
// This gets called on a button click
public void ProcessButton()
{
    ProcessTask(() => 
    {
        // Some code here
    });

    // Code below this does not executes sometime.
    DoSomeOtherWork();
}

private void ProcessTask(Action action)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    task.ContinueWith(r =>
    {
        myModal.Close(); // The modal always gets closed
        // Any code here always executes
    },
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Show the modal dialog which blocks the UI thread
    myModal.ShowDialog();
}
```

For most of the cases, DoSomeOtherWork method executes after the modal is closed. However on occasions, it does not. There is no error/exception occurring. This behavior is observed in production only.

There are many other background operations running in this application so I am not sure if there is any interference. The application is built in .NET framework 4.6

**EDIT**

Additional info:

The Action lambda internally have another

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Some Code here }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
```

Could this be a problem?

Also this code is not causing any deadlock for me as stated by other users.
I even tried logging the synchronization context and managed thread id  in continuation block and it refers the same context and thread id under which the ProcessButton was running.

> Managed Thread Id: 1 Current sync context:
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext

Comment: Do you always create a new myModal object? ShowDialog can only be called once for a window object.

Comment: Yes, I always create a new myModal and then close, Dispose it

Comment: `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());` an extra `)`?

Comment: There could be an error/exception occurring, but you never `await` your `Task`. You're not checking for completion or any attached exceptions either. So any exceptions that are thrown will not be shown.

Comment: @HSharma: How is the continutation of the task supposed to be executed on the UI thread when it's blocked waiting for the dialog to be closed...?

Comment: I assume you have checked that ProcessButton is only called on the UI thread, and that there is only one UI thread?

Comment: @JonasH Yes I did ensure that.

Comment: @mm8 When It indeed is running on UI thread. I logged the synchronization context and managed thread id in continuation block and it refers the same context and thread id under which the ProcessButton was running

Answer (score 0):

The continuation action cannot be executed on the UI thread while it's waiting for the dialog to be closed. Your code will deadlock.

Remove `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to execute the continuation action on the background thread and then use the dispatcher to close the dialog:

```
private void ProcessTask(Action action)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    task.ContinueWith(r =>
    {
        myModal.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => myModal.Close()));
    });

    // Show the modal dialog which blocks the UI thread
    myModal.ShowDialog();
}
```

You may also want to handle any exceptions thrown by `action` but that's another story.

Comment: Do you have any source? A modal dialog will still pump messages. And both BeginInvoke and TaskScheduler should work by posting a message to the UI thread. If there is some difference between how these messages are processed it would be useful with a source explaining the difference.

Comment: Source on what? Why the continuation action cannot be executed on a blocked thread? Try it yourself.

Comment: I did, seem to work perfectly fine for me.  When the task completes it should call `Post` on the supplied synchronization context, and this will post a message to the UI thread, asking it to run the delegate. Even while the UI thread is "blocked" it will still process messages, at least some of them. So what is the critical difference between using a TaskScheduler and BeginInvoke?

Comment: `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` returns a taskscheduler that does the `Post` when queuing tasks. I'm asking why this is any different from using BeginInvoke.

Comment: The code posted in the question does deadlock on my machine and this is probably also the behaviour experienced "on occasions" in "production".

Comment: But your explanation is insufficient. Your claim about "cannot be executed on the UI thread while waiting for the dialog to close" could just as well apply to your `BeginAction`. Why can *that* action be executed, while the action scheduled by the taskscheduler cannot? There might very well be reasons why one works while the other does not, The internal message handling is complex.  But then the answer should explain *why* they are different, and preferably also with some reference.

Comment: Should it? Feel free to write your own answer if you have anything to add. This answer contains an explanation to why the method doesn' get called as expected and an example of how you can solve the issue.

Comment: lets agree to disagree then.

Comment: @mm8 so does that mean this code deadlocked for you every time? because we had this code running for years and just started failing for one particular customer/machine intermittently. Could hardware/processor has any role here?

Comment: @HSharma: Yes, it deadlocked the few times I executed the same code.